# How to share 1 SharedPreferences file between 2 activities

Tags: android, android-activity, sharedpreferences

I have got a `SharedPreferences` file in my **Activity1**.

```
void saveDays(){
    Log.w(TAG, "Start saveDays");
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    editor.putInt("Days", days);
    editor.commit();
}
```

Then I need to use `days` in my **Activity2**. So how can I load it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Activity2, where you want to get access to that preference:

```
int days = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).getInt("Days", DEFAULT_DAY);
```

Where `DEFAULT_DAY` is the default value to use if there is no "Days" preference available.

Answer (score 0):

You want to name the preferences and access them with that name in both

```
SharedPreferences prefs = 
             getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

And then its as simple as retrieving the int...

```
int days = prefs.getInt("Days", 1);
```